# Implicitly load dependency DLL

Tags: .net, dll, f#

I may be missing a whole lot here - I don't know .NET or F# that well. I'm building a type provider, and I'm trying to test it out in the console

I've added a couple of dependencies to my project. One of these has another dependency underneath it.

When I try and run `fsi` (or `fsharpi` on MacOS) I get that I need to add the `-r` flag and include the type provider DLL (because how else does it know to load the DLL?). What I don't understand is why I then *also* have to `-r` all the dependencies. I don't understand the point of a dependency manager (I'm using `nuget` via `dotnet add package`) if it doesn't include the dependencies in some way that other libraries can reference.

I resorted to copying all the DLLs out of `$HOME/.nuget` and into the `bin/Debug` directory, and then everything works as expected.

Am I missing something here? It doesn't seem logical that I have to do this in order to run the application.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but what you're missing is [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/). It has a lot of features for handling NuGet dependencies (better, IMHO, than NuGet itself!). The one you'll find most useful when working with F# Interactive is [the `paket generate-load-scripts` command](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-generate-load-scripts.html), which reads your `paket.dependencies` file and generates a script that will reference *all* the dependency tree (including dependencies of dependencies) for you.

Comment: @rmunn great tip. I feel like this is the second time you've helped me out with this.

I have added paket, and I can now load all my assemblies. I was using paket previously, and had issues, so moved away, but now am back once again.